# Api call Response contains Results Up to limited Posts on Facebook

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, api, facebook

Got response from facebook API and have Next previous in paging for next call how i can use it to get more response. **I want to retrieve all Posts and likes**.

I got Docs Of Cursor Based paging. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

```
  {
"id" : "16163671745458658991",
"name" : "XXXXX",
"feed" : {
    "data" : [{
            "id" : "16163671745458658991_16168041052819454565",
            "message" : "Today is the busy day",
            "created_time" : "2016-11-24T10:15:10+0000",
            "likes" : {
                "data" : [{
                        "name" : "XXXXX",
                        "id" : "16163671745458658991",
                        "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c29.0.100.100/p100x100/399548_10149999285987789_1102888142_n.png?oh=7432daa638606bdffdfdfddb0a8cd92d8607e692&oe=58AEC31D",
                        "username" : "XXXXXpage",
                        "profile_type" : "page"
                    }
                ],
                "paging" : {
                    "cursors" : {
                        "before" : "MTYxNjM2rtrttNzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD",
                        "after" : "MTYxNjM2rtrttNzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD"
                    }
                }
            },
            "comments" : {
                "data" : [{
                        "likes" : {
                            "data" : [{
                                    "id" : "16163671745458658991",
                                    "name" : "XXXXX"
                                }
                            ],
                            "paging" : {
                                "cursors" : {
                                    "before" : "MTYxNjM2rtrttNzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD",
                                    "after" : "MTYxNjM2rtrttNzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "id" : "16163671745458658991_1627615154200860",
                        "like_count" : 1
                    }
                ],
                "paging" : {
                    "cursors" : {
                        "before" : "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemeweweIzSTZANVFl5TnpZAeE5URTFOREl3TURnMk1Eb3hORGd5TWpReE9UazUZD",
                        "after" : "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemeweweIzSTZANVFl5TnpZAeE5URTFOREl3TURnMk1Eb3hORGd5TWpReE9UazUZD"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id" : "16163671745458658991_16168041052819454565",
            "message" : "shareing my first post",
            "created_time" : "2016-11-23T12:50:27+0000",
            "likes" : {
                "data" : [{
                        "name" : "XXXXX",
                        "id" : "16163671745458658991",
                        "pic" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c29.0.100.100/p100x100/399548_10149999285987789_1102888142_n.png?oh=7432daa638606bdb0a8cd934342d8607e692&oe=58AEC31D",
                        "username" : "XXXXX",
                        "profile_type" : "page"
                    }
                ],
                "paging" : {
                    "cursors" : {
                        "before" : "MTYxNjM2NzE3ODY1OfgfgDk5MQZDZD",
                        "after" : "MTYxNjM2NzE3ODY1OfgfgDk5MQZDZD"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "paging" : {
        "previous" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1616367178658991/feed?fields=id,message,created_time,comments%7Blikes,id,like_count%7D,likes%7Bname,id,pic,username,profile_type%7D&since=1479982510&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAF3DC2WN5st6A7pFYMcMG9SErtrtrtsXuFw6ZCesYE9qdJyxdavT8UK5rDklXvebTrM6Ldzxsq5qw0V1oAh48SUrzPMARX2w7N2EMAXneAsLXVGZAkkMUZCJrttrtBnbzhM31PFvcZBfnTPPR7nQZBZBoq5zeEIfPj69kwiMgwG3OBRfBq6ra&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdDjWaUHswHT4a34LWMgiNzzZAOMsRjjjJwFBejKSZBDdHiwCHH8hImcCeXInucceSfUKHgFFbdeseZBhOeiWjbmplCuVouq48cPERomyL91t09RgZDZD&__previous=1",
        "next" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1616367178658991/feed?fields=id,message,created_time,comments%7Blikes,id,like_count%7D,likes%7Bname,id,pic,username,profile_type%7D&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAF3DC2WN5st6A7pFYMcMG9SEsXuFw6ZCesYE9qdJyxdrtrttrttrtavT8UK5rDklXvebTrM6Ldzxsq5qw0V1oAh48SUrzPMARX2w7N2EMAXneAsLXVGZAkkMUZCJBnbzhM31PFvcZBfnTrttrtPPR7nQZBZBoq5zeEIfPj69kwiMgwG3OBRfBq6ra&limit=25&until=1479905427&__paging_token=enc_AdBjxZBNJEadNwBHmz62uCBOwvgJnAR69jYjK0fNfPIhyyQAMSHZB6iR6ECZCocuqR4st5oCviPW0oQMrvLgGzR9AgQUSSNxeuuY5bYS33PLqAaagZDZD"
    }
},
"new_like_count" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use It by calling again API on the **Next** property As Below. **Bit Inefficient**.

```
me/feed?fields=id%2Cpermalink_url%2Cmessage%2Ctype%2Ccreated_time%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom%2Cpicture%2Ccomments%7Bid%2Cmessage%2Ccomment_count%2Ccreated_time%2Cattachment%2Cfrom%2Clike_count%7D%2Clikes%7Bid%2Cname%2Cpic%2Cprofile_type%2Clink%2Cusername%7D&limit=25&until=1482470132&__paging_token=enc_AdD0urtertrt5zUYkQjANrFVG7nVMfkftKfRpIDdVVJd4RGqJy6j8I8O9kWMVOIS09uKGl5SPsg66oGZAU8ZBEc0qmnVwvLqG8qwGKbe8OfZAEJ9PgRFjZBAZDZD
```

Rather Than New API call. You can Use Batch API call Of facebook [Batch Request at Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests)